# Angular-material constant width of button group

Tags: angular-material

I am trying to have constant width of button group, it shouldn't be effected by the number of buttons in it. I am pasting my stackblitz link and image of the result which I want.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r9zyb9?file=styles.css

[image]

As you see in the image, width of buttons is changing because of its number but button group width is constant/same

Answer (score 6):

You can apply some CSS to accomplish this, for demonstration purposes I applied it via in-line style in the HTML so you can see what it is doing, but you could use a custom class if you like.

[image]

You first set the width of the group and the margin... here I am doing 80% of the viewport width.

```html
<mat-button-toggle-group name="fontStyle" aria-label="Font Style" style="width:80vw; margin:1%">
```

Then set **all** of your buttons width to 100% and it will average the total width of container across the number of buttons.

```html
<mat-button-toggle value="bold" style="width:100%">Bold</mat-button-toggle>
```

**Stackblitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r9zyb9-j6nu3j?embed=1&file=app/button-toggle-overview-example.html

Answer (score 4):

i know it's a bit late but i couldn't find any answer to you question an i had the sam issue.

Meanwhile there was an update for MaterialDesigns 1.2.0-alpha01

Before it extended RelativeLayout.
Now the Material Toggle Group is extending LiniearLayout so you can use android:layout_weight="" to fit the childViews percentage from parent view. Here is a code example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toggle_button_group"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:singleSelection="true"
    app:checkedButton="@+id/toggle_button_2"
    >

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/toggle_button_1"
        style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="1"/>

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/toggle_button_2"
        style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="2"/>

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/toggle_button_3"
        style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="3"/>

</com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup>
```

Looks like this.[image]

Hope this helps. Happy coding

Comment: Yeah this is awesome. Thanks! ‍☠️

Comment: Android answer in Angular question, but helped! Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

Using Bootstrap you can achieve this..

```html
<mat-button-toggle-group name="fontStyle" aria-label="Font Style" class="row">
    <mat-button-toggle value="bold" class="col-sm">Bold</mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle value="italic" class="col-sm">Italic</mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle value="underline" class="col-sm">Underline</mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
```

A working stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r9zyb9-uholwy

Thanks.