# Angular mat-button-toggle fit buttons to group width

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular-material

[image: wrong result/wanted result]

Hi,

I want to fit the elements of the first group (the numbers) to look like the second group(noche, mañana...). Change sizes according to the outer element.

I set both the group and individual element width to 100%

The numbers go all the way to 22 but they are cut off.

I used the answer in this question: [Angular-material constant width of button group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54028264/angular-material-constant-width-of-button-group)

The elements are there but they overflow, is there any way to distribute the available width between the 24 buttons without it overflowing?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-etsqjy)

My HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <label>Horas</label>
        <div>
            <mat-button-toggle-group [formControl]="hoursCtrl" multiple>
                <mat-button-toggle *ngFor="let hour of hours" [value]="hour">{{hour}}</mat-button-toggle>
            </mat-button-toggle-group>
        </div>
        <mat-button-toggle-group [formControl]="dayMomentCtrl" multiple>
            <mat-button-toggle *ngFor="let dMoment of dayMoments; let i = index" [value]="i">{{dMoment}}
            </mat-button-toggle>
        </mat-button-toggle-group>
    </div>
</div>
```

My scss:

```
.mat-button-toggle-group {
    height: 20px; 
    font-size: 11px;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.mat-button-toggle {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: can you provide stackblitz

Comment: @Exception added stackblitz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enclosed all under a class wrapper

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <mat-button-toggle-group class="min-width" [formControl]="hoursCtrl" multiple>
    <mat-button-toggle *ngFor="let hour of hours" [value]="hour">{{
      hour
    }}</mat-button-toggle>
  </mat-button-toggle-group>
  <mat-button-toggle-group [formControl]="dayMomentCtrl" multiple>
    <mat-button-toggle
      *ngFor="let dMoment of dayMoments; let i = index"
      [value]="i"
      >{{ dMoment }}
    </mat-button-toggle>
  </mat-button-toggle-group>
</div>
```

Then, in **styles.css** remove the "padding" of the groups-buttons

```
.wrapper .mat-button-toggle-appearance-standard .mat-button-toggle-label-content,
.wrapper .mat-button-toggle-label-content {
  padding:0;
}
```

You can also add a min-width to the group

```
.wrapper .mat-button-toggle-group {
  ...
  min-width:400px;
  width:100%;
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kugojm?file=src%2Fstyles.css)